# osx virtualbox seamless mode

Tags: osx, virtualbox

I have been trying to get virtualbox seamless mode working and am not getting adequate results.

Background info:

> host: Mac OS "Kernel Version 17.6.0"
>    virtualbox: "Version 5.2.12 r122591 (Qt5.6.3)"
>    guest: "4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu"

(although I have tried several different options for host)

I have read many threads about seamless mode not working and none of the ones I read was related to the problem I am having.

- I can go into seamless mode.
- It does show the windows from the guest.
- The guest windows have a large outline around them showing part of the guest desktop picture.
- The dock in the guest is not drawn unless I put a window under it, and I cannot see the whole dock. When it is not visible it is not clickable.

I have tried ubuntu, ubuntu with cinnamon, ubuntu with kde, mint with cinnamon, mint with kde, debian with cinnamon, debian with kde but they all have the same problems.

I tried ubuntu and mint on my ubuntu box and seamless mode was working as expected. The problem seems to be the interaction of OSX and virtualbox. Any insight would be fantastic.

Comment: same with vbox in Windows, only the windows appear. I think it is a recent VirtualBox bug - try an older version. I did not and wont investigate further the problem because in my Windows seamless mode is painfully slow, and I prefer to run a native X server. In my Mac I use VMware Fusion which it is much better.

Comment: Have a look at Fusion and Parallels. I got Fusion because I got a big discount in VmWorld and I am dealing with VmWare at work, I used to prefer Parallels. They are comparable products nowadays, however Parallels was the leader for a good while for Mac.